# Why are there TWO "linux-image-XXX-generic" with different numbers on one computer OS?

Tags: kernel, updates

I've been thrown off track by this many times in the past, but always assumed that I had remembered something wrongly.

It turns out that I have both `linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic` and `linux-image-4.2.0-38-generic`

[image: From software updater while updating]

in my standard installation of Ubuntu 14.04.

What the devil's going on here?

No wonder I have struggled to check my current kernel many times in the past. Are these kernels?

I would usually expect a kernel filename to commence with "vmlinuz". Is that right or wrong?

Here are some more screenshots, of other items that always throw me off course. I don't even know which ones are the same and which aren't.
[image: From uname -a]
[image: From askubuntu questions webpage]
[image: From software updater while updating]
[image: From software updater during update]
[image: From software updater during update]

Edit: I just loaded the pictures one-by-one again, because a couple of the screenshots were missing the first time that I loaded them.

Comment: What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: @edwinksl `uname -r` is more concise - just the kernel release number

Comment: @wjandrea There is no harm getting more information since both flags give outputs that are one-liners anyway.

Comment: @edwinksl Sorry I thought I had added that screenshot when I wrote the post. It's there now.  Before this update, it said `4.2.0-36-generic`. Now it's `4.2.0-38-generic`.

Comment: @wjandrea `uname -r` now gives `4.2.0-38-generic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is a old one and one is a new one. Version 4.4 is the new one, and the latest in the Ubuntu repositories, and version 3.13 is the old one and the one that came with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why then do I have two current kernel series - ie. the 3.x.x series and the 4.x.x series? I would have thought that once the 3.x.x series had been superseded by the 4.x.x series, that it would be retired from use but it looks like I've ended up with a bunch of 3.x.x and a bunch of 4.x.x, which strikes me as inefficient or something.

I can understand keeping previous kernel versions **within** a series to be able to roll back if necessary.

I know that only one kernel will be active in my system at any one time, so I'm not worried about that. I'm just trying to work out what's going on.

Comment: It is good that this kernel is there. If your 4.x kernel fails, you still have your 3.x kernel as a backup.

Answer (score 1):

You are not running two kernels at the same time. Grub has located many more than two different kernels installed on your system. This commonly happens when the kernel has been updated. Hold down shift while booting your system to display grub, you will then see the option to log into your system with either kernel. It is good to keep two different ones installed in case you have a bad experience with a kernel upgrade, you can then boot into grub and use the older working kernel to get your system stable again.

You can remove old kernels if you wish. I think you are identifying the two major kernels on your system 3.x.x and 4.x.x versus the many smaller updates in your 3 kernel

Comment: Always a good idea to keep the previous numbered kernel on you system in case you lose functionality with an update.